# What if tool does not give me any output

Tags: python, python-3.x, tensorflow

I was following the what-if-tool blog and instructions and steps and I could not get any output when I use my dataset. I also do not get any error messages.

Source1: https://colab.research.google.com/github/pair-code/what-if-tool/blob/master/xgboost_caip.ipynb#scrollTo=PzmV_odNPBTb

Source2: https://pair-code.github.io/what-if-tool/learn/tutorials/notebooks/
The code used:

```
import sys
python_version = sys.version_info[0]

# If you're running on Colab, you'll need to install the What-if Tool package and authenticate on the TF instance
def pip_install(module):
    if python_version == '2':
        !pip install {module} --quiet
    else:
        !pip3 install {module} --quiet

try:
    import google.colab
    IN_COLAB = True
except:
    IN_COLAB = False

if IN_COLAB:
    pip_install('witwidget')

    from google.colab import auth
    auth.authenticate_user()

pip install witwidget
!jupyter nbextension install --py --symlink --sys-prefix witwidget
!jupyter nbextension enable --py --sys-prefix witwidget

import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import witwidget

from witwidget.notebook.visualization import WitWidget, WitConfigBuilder
# Dataset used
import dalex as dx
import pandas as pd
data = dx.datasets.load_german()
data
# Transformation
from sklearn import preprocessing
le = preprocessing.LabelEncoder()
data['sex'] = le.fit_transform(data['sex'])
data['housing'] = le.fit_transform(data['housing'])
data['saving_accounts'] = le.fit_transform(data['saving_accounts'])
data['checking_account'] = le.fit_transform(data['checking_account'])
data['purpose'] = le.fit_transform(data['purpose'])
data

# Split Train and Test set 
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
X = data.drop(["risk"],axis=1) # axis: {0 or ‘index’, 1 or ‘columns’}, default 0
y = data["risk"]

X_train, X_test, y_train, y_test = train_test_split(X,y,train_size=0.8, test_size=0.2, random_state=0)
print("Data sucessfully loaded!")

# Model Prediction
import xgboost
model = xgboost.XGBClassifier().fit(X_train, y_train)
y_test_predict = model.predict(X_test)
y_test_predict

# Transform into arrays
X_test = X_test.to_numpy()
y_test = y_test.to_numpy()

# Combine the features and labels into one array for the What if Tool
test_examples = np.hstack((X_test,y_test.reshape(-1,1)))





def adjust_prediction(y_test_predict):
  return [1 - y_test_predict, y_test_predict]

config_builder = (WitConfigBuilder(test_examples.tolist(), data.columns.tolist() + ['risk'])
  .set_ai_platform_model('fairdetect', 'testset1', 'v1', adjust_prediction=adjust_prediction)
  .set_target_feature('risk')
  .set_label_vocab([0, 1]))
WitWidget(config_builder, height=1000)
```

The last code should have given me a visual output but I received nothing.

Comment: Did you execute all the steps? I am able to reproduce the output
see: https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1P5xj7wMTg_CDrkzRYzv9fdc1P-2Va8Om?usp=sharing

Comment: I receive a RuntimeError('<HttpError 403 when requesting https://ml.googleapis.com/v1/projects/GroupA/models/Whatif/versions/v1:predict?alt=json returned "Permission denied... on the Performance and Fairness dashboard